# relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: linux, eclipse, makefile, java-native-interface

I'm trying to run the following makefile for JNI in Eclipse on Ubuntu 14.04

```
CLASS_PATH = ../bin

vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)

all : libSend.so

libSend.so : Send.o
        gcc -fPIC -shared -o $@ $<

Send.o : Send.c Send.h
        gcc -fPIC -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include" -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux" -c $< -o $@

Send.h : Send.class
        javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*

clean :
        rm Send.h Send.o libSend.so
```

When I try to build this makefile. I'm getting the follwing error:

```
make all 
javah -classpath ../bin Send
gcc -fPIC -shared -o libSend.so Send.o
/usr/bin/ld: Send.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
Send.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libSend.so] Error 1
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Why is make not trying to build `Send.o`? Is `javah` actually creating `Send.h` in the current directory? What does `make -d` output?

Comment: Did you try `make clean; make all`?

Comment: @EtanReisner *Why is make not trying to build `Send.o`?*  Because it's already there and won't get recompiled unless `Send.c` or `Send.h` change since those are its only dependencies listed in the makefile.

Comment: @AndrewHenle And the `javah` command to rebuild `Send.h` is being run. Presumably it should be creating the header file and updating its timestamp. That would be why I asked "Is `javah` actually creating `Send.h` in the current directory?" in my previous comment. `make clean` should **never** be necessary for a correctly written makefile.

Comment: @EtanReisner Send.h is created in the current directory

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Thank you very much! make clean; make all worked.

Comment: Does the timestamp of `Send.h` change when `javah` runs?

Answer (score 0):

My code worked when I followed @AndrewHenle's suggestion:

```
make clean; make all
```

Thank you @AndrewHenle.

Comment: This isn't an answer. This is a workaround. Like I said in my comment this should never be necessary with a correct makefile. You are just going to get stuck in this situation again the next time `Send.h` needs to change I believe.

Comment: I ran make clean once. After that I ran my application multiple times without any issue.

Comment: But did it rebuild `Send.o` each time or not? I'm betting it didn't. You didn't see the `-fPIC` error again because the existing `Send.o` is correct this time. If you *intentionally* build `Send.o` incorrectly (or replace it with a text file, etc.) then you will likely hit the problem again.

Comment: I modified my code and tried make all. Send.so rebuilt again without any error. Send.so is rebuilding each time. I checked the time stamps. Can you please guide me on how to proceed if I get that error again?

Comment: Notice I didn't say anything about `Send.so`. I was talking about `Send.o`. And the answer is you need to figure out why `javah` wasn't causing `Send.h` to be seen, by make, as new and thus that `Send.o` needs to be rebuilt. Your output in the post indicates that `javah` ran but that `Send.o` **did not** get rebuilt and **that** is the question. Why did `javah` **not** cause `Send.h` to have a new timestamp and thus cause `Send.o` to need to be rebuilt. Did the class file change? (Perhaps `javah` is smart enough not to replace its output if it doesn't need to.)

Comment: Yes, for the first time Send.o didn't rebuild. But now, Send.h, Send.o and my class file has the most recent timestamps.

Comment: So if you change the class file then `Send.h` is regenerated and then `Send.o` rebuilds? That's possible if the issue was that `Send.o` had originally had a timestamp in the "future" (but make usually yells about that I believe).